# App crashes everytime the "settings" button is hit, how can I debug?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I keep getting this error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)' on a null object reference

and I don't know how to fix it. How can I correct it?

[image: Database Structure]

Code:

```
package com.example.macdate;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.IOException;


public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mNameField, mPhoneField;

    private Button mBack, mConfirm;

    private ImageView mProfileImage;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mCustomerDatabase;

    private String userId, name, phone, profileImageUrl;

    private Uri resultUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        String userSex = getIntent().getExtras().getString("userSex");
        mNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        mPhoneField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);

        mProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);

        mBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        mConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(mFirebaseUser != null && userSex != null) {
            userId = mFirebaseUser.getUid();
            mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userSex).child(userId);
        }

        getUserInfo();

        mProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
        mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveUserInformation();
            }
        });
        mBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
                return;
            }
        });
    }


    private void getUserInfo() {
        mCustomerDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    if(map.get("name")!=null){
                        name = map.get("name").toString();
                        mNameField.setText(name);
                    }
                    if(map.get("phone")!=null){
                        phone = map.get("phone").toString();
                        mPhoneField.setText(phone);
                    }

                    if(map.get("profileImageUrl")!=null){
                        profileImageUrl = map.get("profileImageUrl").toString();
                        switch(profileImageUrl){
                            case "default":
                                Glide.with(getApplication()).load(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(mProfileImage);
                                break;
                            default:
                                Glide.with(getApplication()).load(profileImageUrl).into(mProfileImage);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void saveUserInformation() {
        name = mNameField.getText().toString();
        phone = mPhoneField.getText().toString();

        Map userInfo = new HashMap();
        userInfo.put("name", name);
        userInfo.put("phone", phone);
        mCustomerDatabase.updateChildren(userInfo);
        if(resultUri != null){
            StorageReference filepath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImages").child(userId);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplication().getContentResolver(), resultUri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putBytes(data);
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Task<Uri> downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();

                    Map userInfo = new HashMap();
                    userInfo.put("profileImageUrl", downloadUrl.toString());
                    mCustomerDatabase.updateChildren(userInfo);

                    finish();
                    return;
                }
            });
        }else{
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            resultUri = imageUri;
            mProfileImage.setImageURI(resultUri);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the logcat

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.macdate.SettingsActivity.getUserInfo(SettingsActivity.java:101)
        at com.example.macdate.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:74)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: `mCustomerDatabase` is null at the time `getUserInfo` is invoked - which means you are not handling the error cases correctly (`mFirebaseUser != null && userSex != null`).

Comment: So are there any changes you would like to suggest? i am kinda stumped here @Andy

Comment: I'd guess the user is not authenticating - also verify things like case on the `userSex` variable - "Female" vs "female" - set a breakpoint at the conditional and step through.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble could you provide actual code? I really don't know how to do that. I am fairly new at this. thanks

Comment: Learning to use the debugger in Android Studio is by far your best investment of time : https://developer.android.com/studio/debug .

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put getUserInfo() mothod in the if statement

```
if(mFirebaseUser != null && userSex != null) {
        userId = mFirebaseUser.getUid();
        mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userSex).child(userId);
        getUserInfo()
    }
```